# glew32s.lib undfined reference

Tags: c++, glfw

I use MinGW compiler and Code::Blocks IDE, 16.01.
I have interested in graphic library OpenGL. I've started to find articles and found one.

I've set up glew, freeglut and glfw by myself without using cMaker. Then, I've decided to link libraries into the project. So, I have the following sequence in Linker settings:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\glew\glew32s.lib
C:\MinGW\lib\freeglut\libfreeglut.a
C:\MinGW\lib\freeglut\libfreeglut_static.a
C:\MinGW\lib\glfw\libglfw3dll.a
C:\MinGW\lib\glfw\libglfw3.a
```

Following by [this tutorial](https://habr.com/post/311198/) (in russian language) I've written in linker settings glew32s.lib (with 's'), 'cause it's a static library and I need this one. After that I've tried to compile but get these errors:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\glew\glew32s.lib(tmp\glew_static\Release\Win32\glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'|
C:\MinGW\lib\glew\glew32s.lib(tmp\glew_static\Release\Win32\glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `_imp__wglGetProcAddress@4'|
```

The code I've tried to compile is:

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    std::cout << key << std::endl;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

Then I wrote in linker settings glew32.lib (without 's'), comment `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` line and try again.
The program was compiled successfully. It was run and the result was as it must be.

But I want to use a static library instead of dynamic. How can it be solved?

Comment: When you see the `imp` prefix on an identifier then you know it is looking for a import from a DLL.  So you can tell that the compiler expected to use the DLL instead of the static library.  There is usually a #define that tells it that with "static" in its name.  Google "glew #define static" and it spits out: "On Windows, you also need to define the GLEW_STATIC preprocessor token when building a static library or executable, and the GLEW_BUILD preprocessor token when building a dll"

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it. Reading this [article](https://toster.ru/q/494941) I've found out that static libraries have not **name**.lib format but lib**name**.a format. So, I've set glew libraries up following by this [article](https://habr.com/post/177885/), although, it doesn't work for glew 2.1.0 version but for glew 1.9.0. I will try to do as you write above. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that library 'glew32s.lib' is built with Visual studio. So you cannot link with it unless you change your compiler.

I suggest you get a GLEW library built with MinGW or build one by yourself. Libraries for MinGW are named 'libNAME.a',

Also, dynamic libraries have no limitation on its name, so there could be no difference between static library (instead, they are named, like, libNAME_static.a or libNAMEs.a, ...)